# Extract partial duplicates from a list of lists; return single match with record of origin of each duplicate; Python

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a list in the following format:

```
L = ['apples oranges  x',
     'bananas apples  y',
     'apples oranges  z']
```

For every item in L, if item.split()[0:2] matches another item.split()[0:2] (i.e., 'apples oranges' matches 'apples oranges') then I need to output a single item.split()[0:2] followed by the tags recording the origin of the partially duplicated line.  The tags come from index 3 of each item (i.e, x, y or z).

So, the output of L would be L2:

```
L2 = ['apples oranges x z',
     'bananas apples y']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for line in L:
    name, value = line.rsplit(' ',1)
    d[name].append(value)
```

then you'll have a dict like that:

```
{'bananas apples ': ['y'], 'apples oranges ': ['x', 'z']}
```

So you only need to format the keys and values:

```
[key + ' '.join(values) for key, values in d.items()]
```

And the result will be:

```
['bananas apples y', 'apples oranges x z']
```

Comment: Very concise and well-explained.

Comment: I was looking at something else on Python docs and ran into this freakishly similar example! http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: @user183037 That's a common use for defaultdict :)